# commands do not appear in blue anymore

Tags: winedt, syntax-highlighting, ide

I don't know what buttons did I hit that I am not aware of, but all of a sudden, I stopped seeing the LaTeX commands in blue anymore. I am talking about `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, `\section`, `\begin{table}`, `\bigskip`....all these commands appear in black.

I highly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: This seems like a question about your IDE; what program are you writing your LaTeX in?

Comment: Have you made a syntax error somewhere? Do you have a brace or a quote where it shouldn't be?

Comment: I am using an old version of WinEdt I guess it is 5.3   I don't think it is a syntax error since I opened old files that I have before and they all appeared like this way all in black. Can't distinguish commands from regular text